# Discord.Net bot reply - contains word

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, discord.net

I have just started tinkering with discord.net for creating a bot. I have a very basic bot right now that already replies with my given response when I type the command text. So if I type, `"Hello"` it will reply with, `"...world!"`

However, what I want, is to have the bot reply with a canned response whenever a message contains a certain word at any point. So if a user types, `"Well, hello there"` it will still reply with, `"...world!"` even though the command word is in the middle of the message. I think I may be able to swing it with the `.Contains()` method, but I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task OnMessageReceived(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            if (!(arg is SocketUserMessage message)) return;
            if (message.Source != MessageSource.User) return;

            string[] filters = { "hello" };
            string content = message.Content;
            bool contains = filters.Any(x => content.Split(" ").Any(y => y.Contains(x)));

            if (contains)
            {
                var guild = _client.GetGuild((message.Channel as SocketGuildChannel).Guild.Id);
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{arg.Content} world!");
                return;
            }
        }
```

This is the MessageReceived event that you can get from the DiscordSocketClient. Put this in your CommandHandler.